# Setting any e-mail accout in Android

Tags: applications, android-versions

Can we set Any e-mail address as the main or primary account in Android device like Yahoo! e-mail account?

And with this Email Account, can we get all access to the Google play store?

Comment: I'd say "try and see". It is possible to register a Google account with any mail address (I did that). When logged in with that in the web browser, Play just shows me I have "no devices" (as I didn't setup any device with that account). I guess accessing Google Play should work with it, but I didn't try. Some other Google services might have issues, though – e.g. the device manager even has when using `@googlemail.com` instead of `@gmail.com` addresses, which many people in Germany experienced (gmail.com wasn't available there initially).

Answer (score -2):

No. Android is gmail addresses only.

Comment: As much as I believe this answer, could you provide references to backup this statement?

Comment: Android is a google product. It uses google accounts. When you register the phone it shows you it is connecting to google servers...

Comment: Mine doesn't. It doesn't even have any Google apps on it. It runs CyanogenMod, so yes, it's an Android device. Amazon's Kindle devices run a customized Android version as well, and do not necessarily ship with Google apps. So that's no answer. When asked about the *service* (Google Play Store), the device is not the point: I've registered a non-Google mail address and can access the Playstore with it (it just says "no device connected with this account", as I didn't register any with it). Didn't try to install apps with it, but guess it should work.